How can I adjust the value of a heat source’s heat generation rate using VBA?
I directly add volumetric heat sources from a VBA program using APIs.
I would like to modify Q (Heat Generation Rate).
My goal is to automate thermal simulations for a part composed of two solid bodies named “PLAQUE” and “DISQUE”.
Sub Heat_sources_volumeSetParameters()

    Const nikVolumeSource = 4
    Const nikFTR_topology = 0
   
    Dim SRV As NIKCommonApiSrvLib.BaseApiObject
    Dim NCA As Object
    Dim IA As Object
    Dim MD As Object
    Dim MC As Object
    Dim FDA As Object
    Dim EF As Object
    Dim Feature As Object
    Dim PFeature As Object
    Dim TopFeature As Object
    Dim GoalFeature As Object
    Dim Heat_sources_volume_Feature As Object
    Dim retval As Boolean

    Set SRV = New NIKCommonApiSrvLib.BaseApiObject
    Set NCA = SRV.LoadNIKCommonApiLibrary
    retval = NCA.LoadProductAPI2("Flow Simulation", "2022")
    Set IA = NCA.Attach2RunningObject
    Set MD = IA.ActiveDocument
    Set MC = MD.ActiveConfiguration
    Set FDA = MC.GetFluidDynamicAnalysisProject

    Set EF = FDA.EnumFeatures
    Set Feature = FDA.CreateTemporaryFeature(nikVolumeSource)
    Set TopFeature = Feature.GetInterface("ITopologyBasedFeature")
    Set PFeature = Feature.GetInterface("IParametrizedFeature")

    retval = TopFeature.AddComponent(nikFTR_topology, "PLAQUE")
    retval = FDA.AddTemporaryFeature(Feature)

    NCA.UnloadProductAPI

End Sub


You are trying to do this with the SOLIDWORKS Flow Simulation, right? Because if it is I don't think that there is way to incteract with it, or at least I haven´t found any documentation on that.
